flutter_3d_controller: Flutter3dControllerLoadingException even though model is fully loaded
I'm working with a 3D model - using the flutter_3d_controller package - in Flutter. When I try to reset the camera position or play an animaton, I encounter an exception
Flutter3DControllerLoadingException: The 3D model is not loaded yet or is still loading. All controller functionality, such as playAnimation, camera controls, texture management, etc, should only be executed after the model has fully loaded.
I tried to play an animation whenever you click on the model and reset the position whenever you click the reset-button
The exception occurs in the playAnimation method and in the resetPostion method.
class _ModelDisplayerState extends State<ModelDisplayer> {
  final Flutter3DController _controller = Flutter3DController();
  bool _isModelLoaded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 4,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => {playAnimation()},
              child: Flutter3DViewer(
                src: widget.skinPath,
                progressBarColor: Colors.blue,
                onLoad: (f) => {_isModelLoaded = true},
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => {resetPosition()},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
              label: const Text('Reset'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void resetPosition() {
    if (_isModelLoaded) {
      _controller.setCameraOrbit(0, 0, 0);
      _controller.setCameraTarget(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  void playAnimation() {
    if (_isModelLoaded) {
      _controller.playAnimation();
    }
  }
}


